# Silverlight opacity animation not working programmatically

Tags: silverlight, animation, telerik, opacity

I'm new at Silverlight and trying samples for things animating the opacity of an object programatically.

I've come up with the following code:

```
        MapShape myTestShape= RadMapInformationLayer.Items[0] as MapShape;
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
        brush.Color = Colors.Purple;
        myTestShape.Fill = brush;

        //create a duration object
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        //create the storyboard
        Storyboard story = new Storyboard();

        //create double animation
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

        //set the duration property
        animation.Duration = duration;

        //set the from and too values
        animation.From = 1.0;
        animation.To = 0.0;

        //add the duration to the storyboard
        story.Duration = duration;            

        //now set the target of the animation
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, myTestShape);

        //set the target property of this object
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

        //add the double animations to the story board
        story.Children.Add(animation);            

        if (!LayoutRoot.Resources.Contains("story1"))
            LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("story1", story);

        story.Begin();
```

For the property path I've also tried:

```
1.  new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Opacity)")

2.  new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.Opacity)")

3.  new PropertyPath("(Control.Opacity)")
```

And a few others, I'm having zero luck with this.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: I cannot see any problems with your code. What happens when you execute it? any errors? exceptions?

Comment: Code works fine for a Rectangle.  Maybe this is an issue with animating the MapShape.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Foson and ColinE
ColinE: There are no errors, it just doesn't do anything
Foson: It could be the MapShape object, not sure if it will change your thinking, but it inherits from the Control object?

Answer (score 1):

I have done databinding to MapShape.FillProperty before.

Try:

```
        //create double animation
        ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();

        //set the duration property
        animation.Duration = duration;

        //set the from and too values
        animation.From = Colors.Purple;
        animation.To = Colors.Transparent;

        //add the duration to the storyboard
        story.Duration = duration;

        //now set the target of the animation
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, rect);

        //set the target property of this object
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(MapShape.Fill).Color"));
```

**EDIT:**

As for why your code is not working -- Looking through MapShape.SetShapeFillStroke(),  it appears that Telerik won't bind the MapShape's Opacity to its inner primitive shape's Opacity unless you provide a fill.  Do you have a Fill defined in XAML?  If not, try providing one.  Otherwise, maybe the code is defined too early in the Shape's lifecycle (in or after ReadCompleted)?

```
<telerik:InformationLayer x:Name="StateLayer">
    <telerik:InformationLayer.Reader>
        ...
    </telerik:InformationLayer.Reader>
    <telerik:InformationLayer.ShapeFill>
        <telerik:MapShapeFill Fill="{StaticResource CommonBackgroundLightBrush}" Stroke="#5A636B" StrokeThickness="1" />
    </telerik:InformationLayer.ShapeFill>
```

Comment: Hi Foson, I'll give this a try quickly. Any reason why my opacity code wouldn't work?

Comment: Hi Foson, I've tried your code and what did work was that the map shape changed to transparent, but it's definitely not animating over time, it's instantaneous. The TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)... that does mean 5 seconds right?

Comment: Correction: It didn't work at all, I actually hadn't put in the .Color part of the PropertyPath. When I do add it I get an exception: Cannot resolve TargetProperty (MapShape.Fill).Color on specified object.